# Most brief way to encode binary blob in Dart code?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to encode some binary blob (say, 100KB) in Dart code. Do not want to put it in a separate file, but hope can put it in `.dart` code (because, for example, I want the excellent flutter hot restart instead of rebuilding the Flutter app again and again if the file chages).

What is the most brief way to do so?

For example I can come up with `final bytes = [100, 70, 220, 132, ...];` but it will make the `.dart` file huge.

I can also do `final data = 'aGVsbG8...'` and use it by `base64.decode(data)`, but it takes up 33% extra space in generated binary.

Comment: What size ratio would be acceptable for you? For example, 100K elements = 100K characters?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately those are your options as there's no way to export binary data from a file (i.e., like directly generating a `.o` file that exports a symbol in C/C++) without using either a Dart list or some other form of encoding.

However, if you're dealing with fixed binary data representations, I'd highly recommend looking at types provided in [`dart:typed_data`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-typed_data/dart-typed_data-library.html) to ensure you're storing this data in memory efficiently (e.g., using `UInt8List` vs `List<int>` will use 8-bits per element instead of the 64-bits that can be represented by `int`).